# How to Disable "Windows Default Location" Pop-Up Programmatically?

Tags: c#, wpf, windows

My C#/WPF application triggers the following pop-up message when run on Windows 7 (image below).

[image]

Obviously this would not be good when the application is deployed, since most of my users do not have admin rights to change this anyway.

Is there any way for me to programmatically disable this message before it pops up, from within my C# application?

Comment: Something to do with geo-location, the map in the background can't be a coincidence.  Nothing to do with WPF of course.  Try another library.  Or enter your location so the advertisers know what to show you :)

Comment: @HansPassant - Yes, it's my application, written in WPF, and definitely using geo-location as well. It just triggered this Windows message. I mean if it were me, I would just close the pop-up, but I figure it might confuse users who also see it, or who don't have rights to change that location on their own.

Comment: Well, have you tried giving it a default location to start with?

Comment: @KevinCook - The actual machine? No. But it doesn't matter so much on mine, it's more about anyone else who uses the application. Is there a way I can set the default location of the machine through the C# code of the application?

Comment: Well, you obviously are calling an API to some geolocation service, have you checked the documentation to see if you can pass in some startup values?

Comment: @KevinCook - Even I will upvote that comment of yours. Perhaps I will close the question as being too broad, I just thought someone might have seen it this before and might have known a way to suppress the pop-up off the top of their head.